# How to determine JVM GC throughput?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

What's the simplest way to determine Oracle Java 8 JVM garbage collector throughput, preferably using JDK command line tools?

With the jstat command I can obtain total garbage collection time (GCT column). Based on comparing the changes in this value with GC logs, it seems that the GCT value output by jstat is the cumulative GC elapsed time in seconds (since JVM startup).
Is this correct?

So, can I calculate GC throughput like this?

```
1 - GCT / time_since_jvm_start
```

jstat could be used to obtain both the GC and time since JVM start using the following command:

```
jstat -gcutil -t <jvm-pid> 1000 1
```

Comment: What do you mean with GC throughput? It seems to me when reading your question you are trying to calculate the percentage of time spent in GC?

Comment: Here's the definition from the "HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide": "Throughput is the percentage of total time not spent in garbage collection considered over long periods of time. Throughput includes time spent in allocation (but tuning for speed of allocation is generally not needed)."

Comment: another notion of throughput is megabytes collected per core-time or wall time. anyway, instead of using jstat you could also enable gc logging and use [gcviewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)

Comment: @marko A Throughput is a measure of a rate of something per time unit. e.g. MB/sec or cars per minute. You seem to be looking for a percentage time paused. which is not a throughput. From a wikipedia; "In general terms, throughput is the rate of production or the rate at which something can be processed. When used in the context of communication networks, such as Ethernet or packet radio, throughput or network throughput is the rate of successful message delivery over a communication channel."

Comment: @peter-lawrey My purpose was to use the term "throughput" in the sense defined in [HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/generations.html#sthref19)

Comment: @marko I disagree with everything it says in that statement. Tuning your code for allocation is usually the first thing I do and not done often enough. IMHO.

Comment: @PeterLawrey throughput here obviously also is *"something per time unit"*. Think of it as instructions of application code that can be executed. GC obviously eats into that finite budget. And if an application is about bulk processing of data you generally don't care about latency, you care about the job throughput. So i think the confusion here stems from OP saying *GC throughput* (which is usually measured in MB/s) when he really means *application throughput*

Comment: @the8472 there is a number of things I find confusing about this term; one of them is that throughput is a percentage with a maximum of 100% The slower you application runs due to delays like network/locking, the higher your GC throughput will appear as it spends proportionally less time in the GC.

Answer (score 4):

You are correct in your question. The `GCT` column contains the total time the JVM was stopped to perform garbage collection, both in young GC and full GC.

You could use jstat as you write (`jstat -gcutil -t <jvm-pid> 1000 1`) and look at the first column to see the total time the JVM has been running. Let's call this `uptime`. Both this timestamp and the GC times are in seconds. If you then want to calculate the percentage of time not spent in GC you would do, exactly as you write:

```
1 - GCT / uptime
```

I would argue that calling this throughput is a bit misleading. For example if you use the CMS collector, GC happens in parallel with the application, lowering the application throughput while it does not actually stop the application.